# perforce merging file branched into overlay workspace

Tags: merge, perforce

Assume I have these two directories

```
/root/subdir1
/root/subdir2
```

and a perforce workspace with an overlay, like

```
Root:
  /root
View:
  //depot/project/...  //workspace/...
  +//depot/project/subdir2/... //workspace/subdir1
```

where *subdir2* is overlaid on top of *subdir1*.

At some point I branch (*integrate*) a file from *subdir1* to *subdir2*, and both files keep being changed and submitted to perforce, either on the overlaid workspace, thus under *subdir2* or on another non-overlaid workspace, thus changing the file in *subdir1*.

How do I now merge (*integrate*) the files such that only the file on the non-overlaid workspace exists?

If I merge into the non-overlaid workspace and delete from the overlaid workspace, the file no longer shows in the overlaid workspace.  If I don't delete it, the version before the merge stays there in the overlaid workspace.

Answer (score 0):

For tasks like this, it can be much easier to use a workspace which has no overlay lines in its view mapping. Then it's not so confusing about which repository file corresponds to which local file, and you can refer to all the different repository files without dealing with the filename ambiguities introduced by overlay mappings.

Also, have a look at 'p4 where'; it gives you a lot of information about how a particular file in your workspace is mapped into its corresponding repository location.

Comment: I know which file is which, and do have one or more workspaces with no overlay files to do the integrations.  I just want to find out how to merge the file back into the mainline and have it, from the overlay workspace point of view, like it was never there.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the drawback of using overlays in workspace view specification: Order matters.

If when you apply an overlay, a file has been deleted in this overlay, on top of a folder where this file exist, then the existing file will never show up.

There is nothing you can do about it, as this is the perforce logic of how folders are populated.

You can try to fiddle with you view paths:

```
//depot/project/...  //workspace/...
+//depot/project/subdir2/... //workspace/subdir1
+//depot/project/subdir1/... //workspace/subdir1
```

And you will see your integrated file back.

Overlays are great, but then moving/deleting files can mess up with them. 
Note that if you rename the file as you move it from directory, then you won't have the problem. I.e. if you move/rename a file from:

```
//depot/project/subdir2/my_file_in_dir2
```

to

```
//depot/project/subdir1/my_file_in_dir1
```

And then apply your overlay:

```
//depot/project/...  //workspace/...
+//depot/project/subdir2/... //workspace/subdir1
```

It's OK, as they don't share the same name anymore.

Comment: I'll give you "double overlay" approach a try after the Xmas break.  Thanks.